# Org agenda view: how to express OR when filtering tags?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In `org-mode`, I want to make an agenda view showing all notes tagged with "NOTE" **or** "LOGG". The following code does not produce the result I want:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(("o" "NOTES" tags "+NOTE+LOGG")))
```

This code will sort out all notes tagged with both `NOTE` **and** `LOGG`.

How can I change my code to filter out notes containing either `NOTE` **or** `LOGG`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OR operator is "|".  Searching for `NOTE|LOGG` will find entries with the `NOTE` tag OR the `LOGG` tag.

There is a list of all the available options on the [advanced searching](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html) page of the manual.  The basic operations are:

```
| or 
& and 
+ include matches 
- exclude matches
```

OR always comes *last* in the order of operations.

Regular expression searches are also possible using `{}`.  A search for `+{NOTE\\|LOGG}` will also find entries with `NOTE` OR `LOGG`.