# Org Weekly Agenda filter tags with logical OR

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

### Background information to motivate my question:

With the agenda open, I can press "\" then "+" to show only results containing a certain tag, say *A*. I can then press "\" and "+" again to show results with both *A* and another tag, say *B*. 
These combinations are boolean expressions of the tags **AND**'ed together: *A AND B* for the former and *A AND NOT B* for the latter.

### My question:

I would like to filter my agenda in the same way but with the union of tags *A* and *B*, so that any entries with either tag *A* **OR** tag *B* are shown (*A OR B*). How can I do this?

`org-agenda-custom-commands` can define tag searches using the full boolean expression syntax described [in the manual](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html) (as described in [the answer to this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/15039)), so that defining a custom command like
`(setq org-agenda-custom-commands '(("z" "test" tags "A|B")))`
but **these searches do not produce a weekly agenda**. For example, they are not sectioned by date, they do not only show scheduled and deadline items, and they do not show upcoming deadlines.

How can I filter the weekly agenda using a query for tag *A OR B*?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a skip-function. For details see [this page](https://orgmode.org/manual/Special-Agenda-Views.html). Adjusted to your needs the function there would be:

```
(defun my-skip-tags ()
  (let ((subtree-end (save-excursion (org-end-of-subtree t))))
    (if (not (or (re-search-forward ":A:" subtree-end t)
                 (re-search-forward ":B:" subtree-end t)))
        nil          ; tag found, do not skip
      subtree-end))) ; tag not found, continue after end of subtree
```

This solution does not work, though, if you want to filter by inherited tags. For this case I use the following function:

```
(defun my-skip-inherited-tags ()
  (let (beg end m)
    (org-back-to-heading t)
    (setq beg (point)
          end (progn (outline-next-heading) (1- (point))))
    (goto-char beg)
    (setq alltags (prin1-to-string (org-get-tags-at)))
    (goto-char beg)
    (if (not (or (string-match "A" alltags)
                 (string-match "B" alltags)))
        end)))
```